# How to group list of string using Linq?

Tags: vb.net, linq

I have list(of string) like this:

```
C:\Users\..\Documents\abc_1.1.pdf     ->file name abc
C:\Users\..\Documents\abc_1.2.pdf
C:\Users\..\Documents\abc_2.1.pdf
C:\Users\..\Documents\xxxxxx_1.1.pdf  ->file name xxxxxx
C:\Users\..\Documents\xxxxxx_2.1.pdf
```

How can I use linq and group these file into groups if file has same name.

such as ex above, I want to get 2 groups, so I use the following code:

```
listfile.GroupBy(Function(filepath) As String
                                      Dim filename = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(filepath)
                                      Return Regex.Match(filename , ".+(?=_\d+\.\d+)").Value.ToString()
                 End Function)
```

But this return result is all files.
Can I get collect subsets?

Comment: What output do you expect? Your code snippet works and groups the files. So what do you need? Btw, you can simplify the query: `Dim g = files.GroupBy(Function(x) Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(x).Split("_"c).First())`

Answer (score 2):

I split the stings by the underscore and selected the first element. Then applied the `Distinct` method

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim lst As New List(Of String)
    lst.Add("C:\Users\..\Documents\abc_1.1.pdf")     '->file name abc
    lst.Add("C:\Users\..\Documents\abc_1.2.pdf")
    lst.Add("C:\Users\..\Documents\abc_2.1.pdf")
    lst.Add("C:\Users\..\Documents\xxxxxx_1.1.pdf")  '->file name xxxxxx
    lst.Add("C:\Users\..\Documents\xxxxxx_2.1.pdf")

    Dim newList = (From s In lst
                   Select s.Split("_"c)(0)).ToList.Distinct

    For Each s In newList
        Debug.Print(s)
    Next
End Sub

'Prints
'C:\Users\..\Documents\abc
'C:\Users\..\Documents\xxxxxx
```